# Active Directory Access Rules aren't as specific as dsacls

Tags: c#, active-directory, acl, access-rights

So I'm trying to get the list of ACE from a specific OU.  I found out about the ActiveDirectoryAccess rule class.

The results given from the output don't seems to be as specific as the output from the dsacls command (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771151%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

How can I make my c# code get more descriptive results similar to dsacls? (better displayname)

Here are the a subset of the output results from my test

```
Domain\myGroup
Inherits - Descendents
ObjectType - 00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529
InheritedObjectType - bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
ObjectFlags - ObjectAceTypePresent, InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
AccessControlType - Allow
ActiveDirectoryRights - ExtendedRight
IsInherited - True
PropagationFlags - InheritOnly
-------
Domain\myGroup
Inherits - Descendents
ObjectType - bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
InheritedObjectType - bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
ObjectFlags - ObjectAceTypePresent, InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
AccessControlType - Allow
ActiveDirectoryRights - ReadProperty, WriteProperty
IsInherited - True
PropagationFlags - InheritOnly
-------
Domain\myGroup
Inherits - Descendents
ObjectType - 28630ebf-41d5-11d1-a9c1-0000f80367c1
InheritedObjectType - bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
ObjectFlags - ObjectAceTypePresent, InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
AccessControlType - Allow
ActiveDirectoryRights - ReadProperty, WriteProperty
IsInherited - True
PropagationFlags - InheritOnly
```

Here's the output from dsacls

```
Allow Domain\myGroup         Reset Password   <Inherited from parent>
Allow Domain\myGroup         SPECIAL ACCESS for lockoutTime   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY
                                      READ PROPERTY
Allow Domain\myGroup                  SPECIAL ACCESS for pwdLastSet   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY
                                      READ PROPERTY
```

By looking at some of the objecttype codes under LDAP://cn=Extended-rights,CN=Configuration,Dc=Mydomain

I can tell that 
00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529 maps to Reset Password
but I can't find any matching for - 28630ebf-41d5-11d1-a9c1-0000f80367c1 or bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2

Code to get my output of ACE of the particular OU.

```
[Test]
        public void ForStackOverflow()
        {
            var cfg = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://PathToMyOU");
            var cfgsearch = new DirectorySearcher(cfg);

            cfgsearch.Filter = "(name=*)";
            cfgsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            cfgsearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;


            var res = cfgsearch.FindAll();

            var ouDE = res[0].GetDirectoryEntry();

            var accessRules = ouDE.ObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

            foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ar in accessRules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ar.IdentityReference.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Inherits - {ar.InheritanceType.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"ObjectType - {ar.ObjectType.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"InheritedObjectType - {ar.InheritedObjectType.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"ObjectFlags - {ar.ObjectFlags.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"AccessControlType - {ar.AccessControlType.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"ActiveDirectoryRights - {ar.ActiveDirectoryRights.ToString()}");


                Console.WriteLine($"IsInherited - {ar.IsInherited.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"PropagationFlags - {ar.PropagationFlags.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine("-------");
            }
        }
```

Code I used to get some of the object guid displayname

```
[Test]
public void ForStackOverflowAllExtendedRights()
{
    DirectoryEntry rootdse = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
    DirectoryEntry cfg = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + rootdse.Properties["configurationnamingcontext"].Value);
    DirectoryEntry exRights = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=Extended-rights," + rootdse.Properties["configurationnamingcontext"].Value);
    Hashtable exRighthash = new Hashtable();

    foreach (DirectoryEntry chent in exRights.Children)
    {
        if (chent.Properties["rightsGuid"].Value != null && !exRighthash.ContainsKey(chent.Properties["rightsGuid"].Value))
        {
            exRighthash.Add(chent.Properties["rightsGuid"].Value, chent.Properties["DisplayName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine($"{chent.Properties["rightsGuid"].Value}, {chent.Properties["DisplayName"].Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Update #1 
I managed to find a code snipped (from this book https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=0321350170&tag=technicalibra-20&link_code=wql&camp=212361&creative=380601&_encoding=UTF-8)
to check for what type of account is being affected.

I'm a bit closer now.  Some of the terms don't match (like reset password to User-Force-Change-Password) and some don't show up

Here are results for my previous example.

```
    Identity: Domain\Mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: ExtendedRight
    InheritanceType: Descendents
     ObjectType: 00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529
     InheritedObjectType: bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
 ObjectFlags: ObjectAceTypePresent, InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
{00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529}=
{00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529}=User-Force-Change-Password

    Identity: Domain\Mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: ReadProperty, WriteProperty
    InheritanceType: Descendents
     ObjectType: bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
     InheritedObjectType: bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
 ObjectFlags: ObjectAceTypePresent, InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
{bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}=pwdLastSet
{bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}=

    Identity: Domain\Mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: ReadProperty, WriteProperty
    InheritanceType: Descendents
     ObjectType: 28630ebf-41d5-11d1-a9c1-0000f80367c1
     InheritedObjectType: bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
 ObjectFlags: ObjectAceTypePresent, InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
{28630ebf-41d5-11d1-a9c1-0000f80367c1}=lockoutTime
{28630ebf-41d5-11d1-a9c1-0000f80367c1}=
```

New Test

```
[Test]
        public void ForStackOverflow()
        {
            var cfg = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=CountryTestSync,OU=EDS,DC=d,DC=r,DC=dfait-maeci,DC=gc,DC=ca");
            var cfgsearch = new DirectorySearcher(cfg);

            cfgsearch.Filter = "(name=*)";
            cfgsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            cfgsearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;


            var res = cfgsearch.FindAll();

            var ouDE = res[0].GetDirectoryEntry();

            var accessRules = ouDE.ObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

            SchemaGuidConversion.PrintSD(ouDE.ObjectSecurity);

            string extendedRightsDN = "CN=Extended-Rights,";
            string schemaAtt = "schemaNamingContext";
            string configAtt = "configurationNamingContext";
            Guid samGuid = new Guid("3e0abfd0-126a-11d0-a060-00aa006c33ed");

            var rootDse = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
            var schemaDN = rootDse.Properties[schemaAtt].Value.ToString();
            extendedRightsDN += rootDse.Properties[configAtt].Value.ToString();

            var schemaRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + schemaDN);
            var extendedRightsRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + extendedRightsDN);

            foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ar in accessRules)
            {
                SchemaGuidConversion.PrintAce(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", ar.ObjectType.ToString("B"), SchemaGuidConversion.GetNameForSchemaGuid(ar.ObjectType, schemaRoot));
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", ar.ObjectType.ToString("B"), SchemaGuidConversion.GetNameForRightsGuid(ar.ObjectType, extendedRightsRoot));
            }


            if (rootDse != null)
            {
                rootDse.Dispose();
            }

            if (schemaRoot != null)
            {
                schemaRoot.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Class to get the information

```
  public class SchemaGuidConversion
    {
        public static void PrintAce(ActiveDirectoryAccessRule rule)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=====ACE=====");
            Console.Write("    Identity: ");
            Console.WriteLine(rule.IdentityReference.ToString());
            Console.Write("    AccessControlType: ");
            Console.WriteLine(rule.AccessControlType.ToString());
            Console.Write("     ActiveDirectoryRights: ");
            Console.WriteLine(                rule.ActiveDirectoryRights.ToString());
            Console.Write("    InheritanceType: ");
            Console.WriteLine(rule.InheritanceType.ToString());
            Console.Write("     ObjectType: ");
            if (rule.ObjectType == Guid.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<null>");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rule.ObjectType.ToString());
            }

            Console.Write("     InheritedObjectType: ");
            if (rule.InheritedObjectType == Guid.Empty)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("<null>");
            }
            else
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(                    rule.InheritedObjectType.ToString());
            }

            Console.Write(" ObjectFlags: ");
            Console.WriteLine(rule.ObjectFlags.ToString());
        }

        public static void PrintSD(ActiveDirectorySecurity sd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=====Security Descriptor=====");
            Console.Write("    Owner: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sd.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount)));
            Console.Write("    Group: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sd.GetGroup(typeof(NTAccount)));
        }

        public static string GetNameForRightsGuid(Guid rightsGuid, DirectoryEntry extendedRightsRoot)
        {
            string filter = $"(rightsGuid={rightsGuid.ToString("D")})";
            return GetNameForGuid(filter, "cn", extendedRightsRoot);
        }

        public static string GetNameForSchemaGuid(Guid schemaIDGuid, DirectoryEntry schemaRoot)
        {
            string filter = $"(schemaIDGUID={BuildFilterOctetString(schemaIDGuid.ToByteArray())})";
            return GetNameForGuid(filter, "ldapDisplayName", schemaRoot);
        }

        public static string GetNameForGuid(string filter, string targetAttribute, DirectoryEntry searchRoot)
        {
            string attributeName = null;
            var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(targetAttribute);
            searcher.Filter = filter;

            using (searcher)
            {
                var result = searcher.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    attributeName = result.Properties[targetAttribute][0].ToString();
                }
            }

            return attributeName;
        }

        public static Guid GetRightsGuid(string rightsName, DirectoryEntry extendedRightsRoot)
        {
            return GetGuidForName("cn", rightsName, "rightsGuid", extendedRightsRoot);
        }

        public static Guid GetSchemaIDGuid(string ldapDisplayName, DirectoryEntry schemaRoot)
        {
            return GetGuidForName("ldapDisplayName", ldapDisplayName, "schemaIDGUID", schemaRoot);
        }

        private static Guid GetGuidForName(string attributeName, string attributeValue, string targetAttribute, DirectoryEntry root)
        {
            Guid targetGuid = Guid.Empty;
            SearchResult result;
            object guidValue;
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(targetAttribute);
            searcher.Filter = $"({attributeName}={attributeValue})";

            using (searcher)
            {
                result = searcher.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    guidValue = result.Properties[targetAttribute][0];
                    if (guidValue is string)
                    {
                        targetGuid = new Guid((string)guidValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetGuid = new Guid((byte[])guidValue);
                    }
                }
            }

            return targetGuid;
        }

        public static string BuildFilterOctetString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("\\{0}", bytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Update 2

Here's an example of another entry that is different

```
=====ACE=====
    Identity: domain/mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: CreateChild, DeleteChild
    InheritanceType: All
     ObjectType: bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
     InheritedObjectType: <null>
 ObjectFlags: ObjectAceTypePresent
{bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}=user
{bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}=
=====ACE=====
    Identity: domain/mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: ReadProperty, WriteProperty
    InheritanceType: All
     ObjectType: f30e3bbe-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1
     InheritedObjectType: <null>
 ObjectFlags: ObjectAceTypePresent
{f30e3bbe-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1}=gPLink
{f30e3bbe-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1}=
=====ACE=====
    Identity: domain/mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: ReadProperty, WriteProperty
    InheritanceType: All
     ObjectType: f30e3bbf-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1
     InheritedObjectType: <null>
 ObjectFlags: ObjectAceTypePresent
{f30e3bbf-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1}=gPOptions
{f30e3bbf-9ff0-11d1-b603-0000f80367c1}=
=====ACE=====
    Identity: domain/mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: GenericAll
    InheritanceType: Descendents
     ObjectType: <null>
     InheritedObjectType: bf967a9c-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
 ObjectFlags: InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}=
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}=
=====ACE=====
    Identity: domain/mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: GenericAll
    InheritanceType: Descendents
     ObjectType: <null>
     InheritedObjectType: bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
 ObjectFlags: InheritedObjectAceTypePresent
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}=
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}=
=====ACE=====
    Identity: domain/mygroup
    AccessControlType: Allow
     ActiveDirectoryRights: ReadProperty, GenericExecute
    InheritanceType: All
     ObjectType: <null>
     InheritedObjectType: <null>
 ObjectFlags: None
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}=
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}=
```

Here's the dsacls entry.  I can get the corresponding entry from above but I'm not sure about the *FULL Control* or *List Contents* entries below.

```
Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS   <Inherited from parent>
                                      READ PERMISSONS
                                      LIST CONTENTS
                                      READ PROPERTY

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for group   <Inherited from parent>
                                      CREATE CHILD
                                      DELETE CHILD

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for user   <Inherited from parent>
                                      CREATE CHILD
                                      DELETE CHILD

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for gPLink   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY
                                      READ PROPERTY

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for gPOptions   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY
                                      READ PROPERTY

Inherited to all subobjects
Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS   <Inherited from parent>
                                      READ PERMISSONS
                                      LIST CONTENTS
                                      READ PROPERTY

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for group   <Inherited from parent>
                                      CREATE CHILD
                                      DELETE CHILD

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for user   <Inherited from parent>
                                      CREATE CHILD
                                      DELETE CHILD

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for gPLink   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY
                                      READ PROPERTY

Allow Domain\mygroup             SPECIAL ACCESS for gPOptions   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY

Allow Domain\mygroup             FULL CONTROL   <Inherited from parent>
Inherited to group
Allow Domain\mygroup             FULL CONTROL   <Inherited from parent>
Inherited to user
                                      READ PROPERTY
```

Comment: That is a lot of possibly useful information. You forgot one thing though, you never actually asked a question.

Comment: Done, I edited the question and added a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some of the terms don't match (like reset password to User-Force-Change-Password) and some don't show up

You'll want to grab the `displayName` attribute rather than `CN` for the Extended Rights objects:

```
public static string GetNameForRightsGuid(Guid rightsGuid, DirectoryEntry extendedRightsRoot)
{
    string filter = $"(rightsGuid={rightsGuid.ToString("D")})";
    return GetNameForGuid(filter, "displayName", extendedRightsRoot);
}
```

In your example that would result in "Reset Password"

Comment: Awesome!  any Idea how to get "Full Control" to appear?  Is that the equivalent of GenericAll

Comment: @Lareau Yes, "GenericAll" is the `System.DirectoryServices` term for "Full Control"

Comment: Again awesome!  What about List Content? Does that map to GenericExecute?

Comment: @Lareau Yes (just like you need permission to execute on a folder in order to enumerate its files). See [all possible values here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryrights(v=vs.110).aspx)